# ADAL: Error with getting token on specific machine

Tags: c#, .net, mono, adal

I have a C# app written for pushing some data to MS service (PowerBI) using ADAL for authentication. I have created and compiled it using Mono on Debian Jessie (trying to get as close to production environment as possible). It runs perfectly on this machine but when I move it to production I get an error `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed`. I have read it might be connected to defaultProxy setting in machine.config so I modified my code accordingly but it didn't help. Main differences between production server and my machine are:
Command line only (prod) -> GNOME, Static IP -> Dynamic IP. Both are virtual machines. The full error output:

```
Unhandled Exception:
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed ---> System.Net.WebException: Error getting response stream (Write: failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.RemoteValidation (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientContext context, AlertDescription description) [0x00000] in <filename unk
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpWebRequestWrapper+<GetResponseSyncOrAsync>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.IHttpWebResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse+<CreateByDiscoveryAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse+<CreateByDiscoveryAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenNonInteractiveHandler+<PreTokenRequest>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase+<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext+<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
        ErrorCode: user_realm_discovery_failed
        StatusCode: 0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: user_realm_discovery_failed: User realm discovery failed ---> System.Net.WebException: Erhe authentication or decryption has failed.): SendFailure ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certifica0xffffffff800b010a
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.RemoteValidation (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientContext context, AlertDescription description) [0x00000] in <filename unk
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.validateCertificates (Mono.Security.X509.X509CertificateCollection certificates) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.Client.TlsServerCertificate.ProcessAsTls1 () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage.Process () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.Handshake.HandshakeMessage:Process ()
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.ClientRecordProtocol.ProcessHandshakeMessage (Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsStream handMsg) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.InternalReceiveRecordCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslStreamBase.AsyncHandshakeCallback (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.HttpWebRequestWrapper+<GetResponseSyncOrAsync>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.IHttpWebResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse+<CreateByDiscoveryAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse+<CreateByDiscoveryAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserRealmDiscoveryResponse].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenNonInteractiveHandler+<PreTokenRequest>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase+<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext+<AcquireTokenCommonAsync>d__0.MoveNext () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
        ErrorCode: user_realm_discovery_failed
        StatusCode: 0
```

All the references to `<filename unknown>:0` are not helpful either.

EDIT: I have also tried compiling it on the production machine - same error when trying to run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out myself, quite stupid mistake. I installed mono from default debian repos and they were outdated. I have actually thought about it and added xamarin up-to-date repos, but I didn't notice that on `apt-get upgrade` the mono packages got kept back. `apt-get distro-upgrade` fixed it all. Just have to be careful with this command - can mess up your system.